# Display fixed minimum price in php search results

Tags: php, formatting, currency

We're using an API to display a list of properties in search results and we need to apply a fixed minimum price of £300 for short stays at properties.

Currently, it is possible to input a stay of 1 or 2 nights and for the price for a particular property to display less than £300.

We need (I presume) an if statement to display £300 in these scenarios.

The below is what we have in place to set the price...

```
<?php echo money_format('£%i', $property_price / ( $nights )) ?>
```

Variables are based on attributes from the API.

Please could anyone advise how we can convert this to include something similar to 'display £300 if price returned is less than this amount'?

The suggested edit of the title is incorrect. I don't want to display the right price (?) - that's why I didn't say that... I want to display a fixed price of £300 even if the results from the API return a price less than this amount.

Comment: Rather than downvoting, please could someone kindly explain how I could provide more helpful details in my question? I need to fix this issue this weekend and my web developers won't return back to work until Monday. Thanks

Comment: I did not downvoted... Do you want to do so? I think that they downvoted since it is a dummy question!

Comment: If it such a dummy question please be as kind to offer the solution then....?

Comment: I don't agree with the revised edit as it's not the 'right' price I wish to display.

Comment: You can re-edit the question, but let the title more generic and concise, avoid such an annoying title like "I write 5 in my code but then 4 is printed on then screen".

Comment: Okay, thank you for the suggestion... I see your point. Please can the title be 'Display fixed minimum price in php search results' (I think the reference to the API is probably irrelevant here). Would that be better?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23019/discussion-between-jeanvaljean-and-geoff-jackson)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer comes from a long chat talk with the author and a careful reading of what he was trying to do.

**Answer** 
I see that there is something wrong in your code.
This is right:

```
<?php if ($property_price < 300) $property_price = 300; ?>
<?php echo money_format('£%i', $property_price / ( $nights )) ?>
```

(that of course is equivalent to a max...)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the max function:

```
<?php echo money_format('£%i', max(300, $property_price / ( $nights ))) ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That didn't seem to work :( Made no difference to the price displayed.

Comment: This is not right! The min between 300 and another value is not 300!!! Is just the min!

Comment: oops i meant max of course